# 'Alt'+'Shift' problems on GNOME3 (Ubuntu 18.04+)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

I want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as keyboard layout switcher. The main configuration utility doesn't allow me to do that (it's a default switcher for almost all computer users). Ok, no problem, I can setup it in GNOME Tweak Tool.

But when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in e.g. Firefox, it shows me hidden main menu (like if I press single <kbd>Alt</kbd>). How can I fix it and make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination work correctly in all applications?